# How do I define a object with a field that references its own keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to have a type that references keys of its own object in TypeScript?

In short, I'm trying to make a type for this object:

```js
const items = {
  one: {
    dependencies: [],
  },
  two: {
    dependencies: ['one'],
  },
  three: {
    dependencies: ['one', 'two'],
  },
  four: {
    dependencies: ['one', 'shouldfail'],
  },
};
```

Where the typechecker only fails on element `four`.  Is this possible?

Comment: There is no *specific* type that works this way.  You could write a *generic* type and then a helper function to infer its type argument from the input, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8ZON). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.  For specific types, either you need to write out manually what the allowed keys are but then you can't support arbitrary keys, or you can allow any `string` key whatsoever but then you can't detect what keys were actually used in order to constrain anything.

Instead, you'd need to define a type that's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its keys `K`.  It could look like this:

```
type OwnDependency<K extends string> =
    { [P in K]: { dependencies: K[] } }
```

That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) whose keys are of type `K` and whose property values are of type `{ dependencies: K[] }`.  This represents the relationship between the keys and the `dependencies` elements.  For example, `OwnDependency<"a" | "b">` evaluates to `{a: {dependencies: Array<"a" | "b">}, b: {dependencies: Array<"a" | "b">}}`.

---

Unfortunately there is no inference for generic type arguments in generic types, so if you wanted to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable of type `OwnDependency<K>` you'd have to write out `K` manually, which is redundant and annoying:

```
const i: OwnDependency<"a" | "b"> = {
    a: { dependencies: [] },
    b: { dependencies: ["a", "x"] } // error
    // --------------------> ~~~
};
```

That works, but you had to write `"a" | "b"`.

The only way to get generic type argument inference in TypeScript is with a generic *function* (not a generic *type*).  So we can make things better by writing a helper generic identity function.  All it does is return its input, but we can use it to infer `K` without writing it out.

The idea is that you'd write

```
const i = ownDependency({
    a: { dependencies: [] },
    b: { dependencies: ["a", "x"] } // error
    // --------------------> ~~~
});
// const i: OwnDependency<"a" | "b">
```

and it would be just like the code above except that `K` is inferred for you.  It's just about the same amount of writing for the user: `const vbl: Type = value` versus `const vbl = type(value)`.

So now we just need to implement `ownDependency()`.

---

As a first approach you could try this:

```
const ownDependency = <K extends string>(
    o: OwnDependency<K>
): OwnDependency<K> => o;

const i = ownDependency({
    a: { dependencies: [] },
    b: { dependencies: ["a", "x"] } // error
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
});
// const i: OwnDependency<"a" | "x">
```

Oops! There's an error, which we want, but it's the *wrong error*.  The compiler inferred `K` from the contents of `dependencies` instead of from the keys, so it's upset that there's a `b` property at all.

To fix that we want to block inference from the array elements.  There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to have some way to say "please don't infer the type argument from this particular place".  There's no native support for that yet, but there are ways to get similar behavior for some use cases.

One way to do it is to add a second type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first, as shown here:

```
const ownDependency = <K extends string, L extends K>(
    o: { [P in K]: { dependencies: L[] } }
): OwnDependency<K> => o;
```

Here the compiler will infer `K` from the keys of the input, and `L` from the elements of the `dependencies` array.  So `L` doesn't affect the inference of `K`.  But since `L` is constrained to `K`, the compiler will check it, and complain if there's a mismatch.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const i = ownDependency({
    a: { dependencies: [] },
    b: { dependencies: ["a", "x"] } // error
    // --------------------> ~~~
});
// const i: OwnDependency<"a" | "b">
```

Perfect.  The compiler inferred that `i` is of type `OwnDependency<"a" | "b">` without us needing to write out `"a" | "b"` ourselves.  And we get the same error as before: the `"x"` array element is called out as a mistake.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8g7gOwCIUggJhBBjEAeAaSggA9gt0BnKS4AJwEsEBzAPigF4AoKXqAbygBtAApQmUAgF0AXAKiY0mHAwiU5BIVKgBfXVy7YA9glri58ZKgpZceAEQBDe1AA+UewCN77DgJ58jnKCijYqanJaugA0AbyewQrWGLaq6sJO9tEe3tn2JPbaegD0xcR0dEZ0cVClUAC0jU3NLa3N7AB+XVw6ANwGhiZmRogoSrYgAEKO6JxQhMRkFNS0jCysABQ1Rhajycp2BKxcAJS7VuM4+Eec7Eb9g6bA4gCMcyMXYbjT6Bv8NUF5KEUuF0lEdLE+FAEkD9qkIhlnHkCkVamUIBUqjVSl1cXj8QTCR0eid+nVjE9Xucxl98Jk3B4CsdHsM9pdcHMFqRyBgVvQmMxsgAZRY8qiSTbbRKicQISSyWHstJyIXg-RnWBs2mEXx3B4GClmBgAJneWpBuD+AMSwIOyuERUhfBhIThoMimWRhV0aPKlWqULqbWDLU63R0pK45KGzxN1Lddnp7i8PgMQA)

Answer (score 0):

There is also an alternative way if you dont want to define the allowed keys in advance.
With this solution, the object keys get inferred, and control which references are allowed.

Downside to this solution is that the type checking is a bit detached, and doesnt happen directly at the constant definition.

[Playground with all the code below](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEF5NBVAXBLANqWBPADgUwM4UgWACgiRQAFAQwGMBrCgc3gDt7R5cnMqdsKAnVABpQAIy4UArtkygJTeAHsmKDDlAVYKABYyt8ejuybEmAG6ZEJMAoBmoTAA9YmJgBNsAWiqJJ03PUxjBQUsV1AFcz5hZiNMCjDbUERgmkwwjXVcClAAdy0FEyI0LHJqOgCAHgAVAD4IUABBPj4KVGqagG4i1VAANQpEeFcAJS4FPlcAaUxUXHBQIz5mVgAfUCYJAFsxPlA17FRtgq7iU9JIeYBlLCp4G1Rl7Rkbcc2MxIUJXdcNbIuiKygaaocJ2WA6cIiABWXFg3RKwPqi2WJ1IxRkiXBGOhsNwpgGEjU4IyfEwNkwpKY3HCWN2qVmoLYsGkiBs8Jko3JlO4FUmAFEAJr1YF1eYAb1JNgAXEDBXtQKN4kpEKgmi02vyBTUAL6osDoxlYyEwqjM0D4xCE3DEzT8FyaGxfWlJFJpdSwQSAkQSW2IZI5N3MdSIZx8JgaeDmFAKJ6gSUUlzcbDs0qoZLxeobbYUvV9AlqAb+wPKT67BQ400p-qWzC8uXzEX1TkJqm1zV1NaUNMKeIAs5gC6gKqqa0xqg6WigF67Fl2ePctT-fugADiLgp8CoKhKrjJzEeRunm0NEPLJo9gKYCk0464NEe07jZJb1IpfHGycIBub3OWdaFjjOG4uDVkMoxUOMUwzHMQIzMIvQNAAMtAfL1F26ZhGsP6JpgooKmMEz-vBSEoZ0fZohCEGktuMg2qAt60LgdwLBYc7PguWTURaQyAgAFPMyogvO0agPSuCJPAzKsQAlCmlysdhVJ-gA8gAQgAUvYTguO4+FcomyyikQoAmaAamaYBOm4IptwsBUzBcrKAqXNETCOQhyF8pcNTGaZfkAPylLQDC1h5KHeVpQG6ZQwWVNWhL-t5PmEH5qWmYFNl-pqLl9CRXnJWlaUypwkS+UV6xmDmfaAoO0C8AEeDgOR+qnhWmh0QGuQUEw7UxgaDE0AAdEQEFMEYoAAJJVHyACylz1GKZVTsEMoAIwAEwAMyeilpkiPwMpik+0qgAA2gARPtfDncI50vAo50ALqgNqO1+ftABeh3HTKd3BOdL1ENqmT0Uo428Ag2A2PAaiZSwuYeHUiOgMjADCE40GwdiljRuTjDQ2Ayuj3UNd1ILIiwInZPS2gZK4Cg4D1WnsJoQY42esLDYQpCFSZmCDfQg30VoJMyJd-AA7AMbi+dQuXBIri7kwKqxv1GOiBYCg5KAARmqSrg7TzvPGybvPMK4m4RpT2Tzjh9jNOMzW4wNB6teeoC7tDnBhBbpKmirFAiBE-OAhNZpXqzTAeOgPjUugCjYNg8AiCYwjYDGnWcG6UsezGkmgDopJc6Qqk+rIbnjLAcgaBYIJ0ZscRjbT7UQm+4xsFkoiSYCFvYKNnCmm6NjvseRoc6aHtcD4LQIEoXOjeNA1VCLsATdg8msnD9AyhvNhbxU6KJFNs0RfMx9zR0QA)

**Utility Types**

```
// Packaging is necessary, because union types at the highest level
// of extends-clauses get looped over, instead of looked at as a whole
type Package<T> = Array<T>;
type ValidRecordKeys = string | number | symbol;
```

**Specifying the format of our data**

```
// Key of the object
type Key = string;
// type of the objects values that reference other keys of itself
type Reference<KEY = Key> = {ref: KEY | ReadonlyArray<KEY>};
// type of the objects values that arent further looked at,
// but allowed in alternative to the references
type Payload = number;
// Values allowed in our object
type Value<KEY = Key> = Reference<KEY> | Payload
```

**Types to check for self references**

```
// Generic type defining the form of the object,
// not checking for reference errors
type Referencing<KEY extends ValidRecordKeys = Key, VALUE = Payload | Reference> = Record<KEY, VALUE>;

// the core type that checks if self references are valid
// (= only refer to keys of itself)
type SelfReferencing<OBJ extends Referencing> =
    OBJ extends Referencing<infer KEYS, infer VALUES>
        ? Package<VALUES> extends Package<Value<KEYS>>
            ? Referencing<KEYS, VALUES>
            : never
        : never;
```

**Usage**

```
// the object that we want to type check.
const ITEMS = {
    foo: 123,
    bar: { ref: ["bar", "foo"] },
    baz: { ref: "foo" }
} as const satisfies Referencing;
// -> -> -> Check if our type works: Change any string to a key that doesnt exist in our object.
//          e.g. change "bar" to "ba". Suddenly the type check below gets red,
//                                     indicating a reference error

// type checking the object defined directly above.
// Its not in-place possible, so we need to do it here.
// But unfortunately that means that the error is a bit
// disconnected from the object declaration.
const checkThatIsSelfReferencing: SelfReferencing<typeof ITEMS> = ITEMS;
```